# What is this uniform (circa 1900, probably NE USA)?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

I'm trying to identify this uniform. The glass negative image is of boys wearing the uniform and the date is 1900-1910[image: negative images of two boys in uniform] The image is from a glass photo negative circa 1900. It appears to be a boy's group or academy, possibly located in NE US.

Same image, inverted and flipped:
[image]

Comment: @VirgniaSday, welcome to the site; I've edited your comment into the question; everything you know should be in the question; you should almost never comment on your own question.

Comment: Thanks @justcal; that helps quite a bit

Comment: Hard to make out the lettering on the collar and cap but HMA or maybe NMA, MMA seems likely - some US military academy?

Comment: Look into *KMA*, [Kearney Military Academy](http://www.bchs.us/BTales_199301.html).

Comment: Is this photo a crop of something larger?  And if it is, can we see that?